# How to group custom markers in a custom view?

Tags: view, eclipse-plugin, grouping, markers

I am creating an eclipse plug-in that verifies XML and XSL code by applying some specific rules, and which generates some custom error markers (ex: *Error, Warning, Info*) in a custom view (called *PCC Markers*).

I create my markers like this :

```
marker = resource.createMarker("pccplug.myMarker");
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, message);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
```

Here is my plugin.xml :

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport">
   <markerField class="pccplug.views.Recommendations" id="champRecommendations"
          name="Recommendations" /> 
   <markerContentGenerator id="pccplug.views.myCustomMarkerGenerator" 
          name="My Marker Generator">
     <markerTypeReference id="pccplug.coolMarker" /> 
     <markerFieldReference id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.severityAndDescriptionField"/> 
     <markerFieldReference id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceField" /> 
     <markerFieldReference id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.pathField" /> 
     <markerFieldReference id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.locationField" /> 
     <markerFieldReference id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerType" /> 
     <markerFieldReference id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.priorityField" /> 
     <markerFieldReference id="champRecommendations" /> 
   </markerContentGenerator>
</extension>
```

My problem is that all the errors are not grouped, they are all one after the other :
[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V5LG.jpg)

And I would like to have them grouped by categories (ex: SEVERITY or PRIORITY), as it is already the case in the Problems View : [My desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs2li.jpg)

How can I create these groups of markers (I tried almost every MarkerField,Type,Group, but I couldn't do it) ?

Does anyone has any idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Your current output and desired output are the same, so I guess you have achieved what you need already ;-)

You have to specify defaultMarkerGrouping in your markerContentGenerator. As in:

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport">
       <markerContentGenerator id="pccplug.views.myCustomMarkerGenerator" 
              defaultMarkerGrouping="org.eclipse.ui.ide.severity"
              name="My Marker Generator">

... others here ...
       </markerContentGenerator>
    </extension>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! And sorry, I put images at first but I didn't have the rights to show them, so I put links, but it seems that I failed the first one :) I just edited it. I tried what you said, and i'm quite sure it is what I am looking for, but it is not working, and I still don't know why

Comment: It should work. If doesn't, then it sounds like a bug. If you can reproduce with a sample plugin, I would suggest you to raise a bug: http://bit.ly/NewBugInPlatformUI I'll look into it

Comment: I did as u said and reproduced it in a sample plugin, but I noticed something weird : it seems to be working when I change my custom marker view, <a href="http://img541.imageshack.us/i/customview.jpg/">by letting an empty string in the super() invocation</a>.

Comment: I can't refer to my custom markerContentGenerator (as u did in your guide : http://www.eclipse-tips.com/how-to-guides/14-creating-a-custom-marker-view), or it doesn't work

Comment: Thats strange! Can you please raise a bug and attach the sample plugin? I'll investigate

Comment: No problem, but I made some changes, and it will take some time to reproduce it. I'll post the link as soon as I have finished.

Comment: Sorry but I won't have the time to raise a bug (I was given another project in the same time). Thanks for your time