# Is there a way to group markers in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

Lets say I am working on multiple tasks and I want to group the markers like bookmarks, TODO lists... based on the tasks I am working on than the default sorting that eclipse provide. Is there any configuration in Eclipse that will allow me to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Please look at this, it can help you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572465/how-to-group-custom-markers-in-a-custom-view

Answer (score 0):

The `Problems` `Bookmarks` and `Tasks` views all have a `Sort By` option that lets you sort by the file path which effectively arranges them by project.

This option is accessed via the small down arrow (triangle) at the top right of the view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I didn't make my question clear. Updated question for more clarity.